# Bind Datepicker event on mat-card

Tags: html, angular, highcharts, angular-material, event-binding

All I need is to update (re-run) my mat-card section (consists with a bar chart ) once the date changed each and every time.here is my code

Datepicker code

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="19%">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date"
        (dateChange)="getDailySummary($event.target.value)">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker  #picker ></mat-datepicker>
 </mat-form-field>
```

mat-card

```
<mat-card fxFlex="1 1 70" style="position:relative" class="mat-elevation-z0">   
    <app-widget-barchart [XAxisData]="XAxisData" ></app-widget-barchart> 
</mat-card>
```

Could someone help me to sort this out ?

Comment: Not sure I understand. the data does not change?

Comment: Related data ( X,Y Axis data ) set is updated but chart does not re-draw with the latest data.

Comment: @Snow_Flaki Could you reproduce your code as an simple demo with a sample data which I could work on?